# Modify the "authenticated users" group in a folder in full control

Tags: powershell, batch

I need to modify the "authenticated users" group in a folder and put it in full control.

I tried a powershell script it does not work and in batch, is it possible to help me?

Here is batch :

```
icacls c:\TEST /grant *S-1-5-11:(f)
```

and powershell:

```
$FolderPath = "C:\Program Files\Eliot"
$ACL = Get-Acl  -Path $FolderPath
$SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-11")
$Rule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($SID.Value, "FullControl",”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”)
$ACL.SetAccessRule($Rule)
Set-Acl -Path $FolderPath -AclObject $ACL
```

Comment: This would mean `FULL CONTROL` allows any authenticated user to adjust the ACL to remove whatever security you set. This is why I use `MODIFY` rather than full control unless they are admins of the environment/system.  so full control, allows access to change Access Control List set on files and folders

Comment: To fix this, just use PowerShell but you will want to remove and not use the line `$SID` and for the `$Rule` line use `$Rule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users", "FullControl",”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”)` naming authenticated users out rather than the SID. Actually the same with the icacls too as `icacls c:\TEST /grant "authenticated users":(f)` check some of my icacls answers though here if needed: https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A510662+body%3Aicacls